# Transpilation of ES6 for unit tests

Tags: ecmascript-6, aurelia, transpiler

I am using babel to transpile my JS using Aurelia framework but ES6 unit tests execute during the deployment process - I need them to run before we get to deployment so that I can validate or address issues beforehand.  Anyone run into transpilation issues while trying to run js jasmine unit tests?